# Dojo EnhancedGrid Scrolling with JsonRestStore

Tags: rest, dojo, grid

I am using a dojo 1.6 EnhancedGrid with a JsonRestStore as shown in the snippet below.  I have about 15000 records of data.  When the vertical scrollbar for the grid is dragged down in order to scroll, it takes a long time to get the data visible in the grid.  After some debugging, I noticed that the single act of scrolling sends 4-5 GET requests to the server.

Is there a better way to solution this, or is there a way to insure that only the last GET request is sent to the server?  I was able to capture the onscroll event, but wasn't sure how to prevent the GET request from being sent.

```javascript
store = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({
    target:"myurl",
    idAttribute: 'id', 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: true});       

mygrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    id: 'mygrid',
    queryOptions: {ignoreCase: true},
    sortInfo: '3',
    store: store,
    structure: my.grid.structure,
    selectionMode: "extended",
    autoHeight: 12,
    plugins: {indirectSelection: true},
    fastScroll: false
},document.createElement('div'));
dojo.byId("datagrid").appendChild(mygrid.domNode);

// start the grid 
mygrid.startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have that much information to handle i would suggest you to use the pagination-plugin for the enhanced Grid. The advantage is that only a certain number of data records will be loaded at once.

have a look here:http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html#id2

Regards, Miriam